# How to replace this " / " from a string, for example "one / another one" to "one/another one"

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace this: " / " from a string.

For example: "one / another one" ---->  "one/another one"

It just removes the spaces between the slash.. no the orher spaces.

Thanks.

Comment: As in, replace `" / "` with `"/"` ? What have you tried? Why didn't it work out? I ask because on the face of it, this is a fairly simple operation, so it feels like there could be something I'm misunderstanding..

Answer (score 0):

This regexp will strip out any runs of whitespaces around slashes, but keeps the slashes intact.

```
> "one / another one / yet some more / until the end".replace(/\s*\/\s*/g, '/')
  "one/another one/yet some more/until the end"
```

If you need to keep e.g. `////` intact, use `+` for the quantifier:

```
> "one / another one / yet some more / until the end (yet this //// remains)".replace(/\s+\/\s+/g, '/')
  "one/another one/yet some more/until the end (yet this //// remains)"
```

Comment: Anyone can comment, why -1 on this?

Comment: By definition " // " should not be replaced.

Comment: @JavaScript And... this doesn't replace ` // `?

Comment: " // " should remain " // " according to the task given. Also "     / " should end up as "    /". But I do not know how strict the question is :-)

Comment: Added the option to keep multiple runs of slashes as-is. Two-character change...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
console.log("one / another one".replace(/\ \/ /, '/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

*You did'nt specified the language;* In my answer I will be using Python;
use -
`string_name = string_name.replace(' / ','/')` (where string_name is name of variable in which you stored the actual string)

'replace()' is used here , in the first argument you provide what you want to replace and
in the second argument you provide with what you want to replace

Comment: It kinda is tagged a `javascript`.